# 301 redirect for all content - domain.org to domain.com

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite

After trying several solutions I just can't seem to get this to work.

I owned a .org and had urls like

http://mydomain.org/view/3242343
http://mydomain.org/login
http://mydomain.org/page/5

and I now have the .com and want all of them to be taken right to their .com equivalents:

http://mydomain.com/view/3242343
http://mydomain.com/login
http://mydomain.com/page/5

etc.

The rules I've tried so far seem to take any URL from .org and just send them to the root of mydomain.com.

What htaccess rule do I need?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming it's an `.htaccess` in the `DocumentRoot` of the .org site (and not the .com site, which would need a `RewriteCond` to prevent a redirect loop):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: This doesn't work - redirects http://mydomain.org/view/9 to http://mydomain.com/. htaccess is in the documentRoot of the .org

Comment: @barfoon In fact it does not.  The `$1` contains the information captured in the match; in this case, everything except the root `/` due to the context of the `.htaccess`.  You likely have some config still in place somewhere in your Apache configuration from another attempt.  Change it to something like `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/spleen/$1 [R=301]` to verify that this config isn't the one doing the redirect.  Check the `<VirtualHost>`?  And make sure you've reloaded the service if you've made changes elsewhere than `.htaccess`.

Comment: I just tried this and that is the result I got. I have not touched the <VirtualHost> on either domain since obtaining both. I even removed all rules on the .com htaccess to see if there was a conflicting rule. No change.

Comment: @barfoon Umm.. what result is it that you got?  With what request URL?

Comment: I typed in http://mydomain.org/view/9 and I got sent to http://mydomain.com/

Comment: @barfoon Right - I'm saying that if you change your new rule to point to somewhere different, you'll be able to verify that it is the rule that's being hit.

Comment: Changed it and got a different result. Looks like the /view/9 url was cached in my browser. My apologies and thanks for your help